# Mocking HttpContext in MVC **Outside** of the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, moq, viewmodel, httpcontext

**Scenario**

We're developing a new MVC web project and we're trying to adhere to the Skinny Controller pattern as described in this article http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/

As part of one of our actions we are retrieving some navigation data (Menu structure) from the Cache.

**Problem**

I order to maintain the skinny controller pattern we'd like to have the cache check call in the ViewModel, which we have tried and we know works, using the following code.

```
var cachedCategories = (List<Category>)HttpContext.Current.Cache["Categories"];
if (cachedCategories == null) {
       cachedCategories = _service.GetCategories().ToList<Category>();
       HttpContext.Current.Cache["Categories"] = cachedCategories;
}
```

However when it comes to unit testing it we hit a problem. Since we are not **directly** passing the HttpContext into the ViewModel we have no idea how to go about mocking the HttpContext.

We're using Moq and while we have some options (one is to pass the context from the controller to the viewmodel at instantiation) those options require changing the code purely to make the tests work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could put a property on the controller which is assignable to a local variable, if it's null it assigns the HttpContect.Current, and returns HttpContextBase, and you can assign the HttpContextBase from the test. If that makes sense.

Comment: Infact if you're using an IoC framework you can automatically assign HttpContext.Current to HttpContextBase property (or constructor), then you can just have a field or auto property. (hmm blog post coming up on this I think ;))

Comment: Adding a property just for testing purpose is one of the options we came up with but we'd rather not do that. We're trying to avoid adding code purely for testing sake.

Comment: You're not adding a property purely for testing, your abstracting away a dependency. It's just how to know the beach approach to take because I don't know if you're using a IoC framework or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately we choose to modify our code to allow for easier testing.

We accomplished this by passing the HttpContext to the ViewModel at instantiation as I mentioned in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

mock the HttpContext is a huge work as it is one of the biggest object you will see in all your life so probably is better don't mock it.(http://volaresystems.com/Blog/post/Dont-mock-HttpContext.aspx)
Anyway you could use the one in MVCcontrib (http://www.codeplex.com/mvcContrib) the file MvcMockHelps shows how it is done.

Comment: Not mocking it is not an option as the test fails with an object reference exception.

Comment: you can use the MvcMockHelps which is in the MvcContrib project
as showed on my answer
The HttpContext has hundred of dependencies which you should mock too
I would go for the MvcMockHelps :-)

Comment: I've had a quick peek at MvcContrib and while I agree it's very useful I'm not sure I understand how it can help me in this instance. "The TestHelper assists by providing a Controller Factory that creates controllers with internal data members correctly initialized." My issue is that I'm trying to mock the HttpContext **outside** of a controller inside the ViewModel.